# Express routes - best way to make a url params.id serve static and dynamic content

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Suppose I have a urls like

```
www.foo.com/abc
www.foo.com/huyr
... etc
```

where 'abc' and 'huyr' in this example are IDs, and i'd fetch info from the database where the key is that id.

But suppose I also want static links (that'll serve static pages) to follow the same url format:

```
www.foo.com/about
www.foo.com/contact
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Right now I have something like this in mind

```
exports.view = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id
    switch (id) {
        case 'about':
            // load 'about' controller
            break
        case 'contact':
            // load 'contact' controller
            break
        default:
            // proceed with this function
    }

}
```

Is this the best approach? is there a more efficient/organized way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way, in my opinion, would be to serve those pages, static or not, like you would with any other page.  Respond to the GET request with the right page.

```
// will respond to http://www.site.com/about
app.get('/about', function( req, res, next ) {
    res.render('about.ejs'  // etc
});

// will respond to http://www.site.com/contact
app.get('/contact', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('contact.ejs' // etc
});

// will respond to any first subdir (iirc) http://www.site.com/(?)
app.get('/:id', function ( req, res, next ) {
    var id = req.param['id'];

    // db query, etc
});
```

You static pages of course can be in a route to make it cleaner.  Only thing you need to make sure of is you respond to those static routes before the id route, or else you will be responding to the about/contact url with the route that you want responding to the ids.  Order matters here.

Comment: Ended up going this way, however, app.get('/:id', cb) always seems to get called (I have it as the last route). I have a console log in it, and regardless of the url i go to, i see the console.log output

Comment: app.get('/:id, cb) should always get called for any directory besides the ones above it (about/contact). Unless you are calling 'next()' from about/contact routes, then express will try to match the next thing, which would be the '/:id'. So don't call next() from your 'static' page routes if you are.

Comment: I don't. But that is outside the scope of this question. I'll figure out. thanks!